# Ubuntu 18.04.1 iso modifications with Cubic. not able to install gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: gnome, 18.04, iso, customization

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1
I have installed Cubic.
I used the latest Ubuntu 18.04.1 iso to customize with Cubic.
I could install `git`, `make`, but not able to install `gnome-tweak-tool`
Any ideas?

Comment: `gnome-tweak-tool` is in the universe repo, did you enable it?